# Registering Mobilink with Mobile Device Center on Vista has errors

Tags: sqlanywhere, mobilink

I have a bat file that I am using to try and register Mobilink with the Mobile Device Center on Vista. (I am using version 11 of Mobilink)
Script:

```
mlasinst -k ./ -v ./
```

I have copied mlasinst as well as mlasdev.dll and mlasdesk.dll to the same folder and am running the above command to get the sychronization process to run.(I have tested the above script on Windows XP and it works).  When I try to copy the same files to a Windows Vista machine, I run the script and restart the computer.  I then follow the directions from  Sybase's website namely I

"From the Windows Mobile Device Center window, click Mobile Device Settings and then click Change Content Settings. 
Select MobiLink Clients and click Save to activate the provider. 
To see a list of registered applications, click Change Content Settings, click MobiLink Clients, and then click Sync Settings. "

Everything works on Vista except for when I click on "Sync Settings"  when I click on it I get an error saying that there are no settings to administer.

My question is how do you get Mobilink to work with Vista and its Mobile Device Center?  I have read all of the documentation I can find but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juen 23rd Comment

For those following at home, as a result of this post, our QA Department was able to reproduce this problem with the Windows Mobile Device Center on Vista when using a Windows Mobile 6 device, and we're looking into it.  Everything seems to work fine with a Windows Mobile 5 device, which we used for our initial testing.

June 19th Comment

I really wanted to leave a comment, since this isn't really an answer, but my repuation wasn't high enough to do so.  Oh well, I'll post a poor answer and watch my reputation go down.  It's the price I'm willing to pay. :)

Our QA group tests mlasinst with Windows Mobile Device Center, but you're obviously doing something different, or more likely your machine setup is slightly different.  To get to the bottom of this, we'd likely need to look into what registry settings are changed as a result of mlasinst running, but before I spend too much time figuring out what's going on here (including figuring out what the proper questions to ask are), I should point out that I would recommend synchronizing using TCPIP or HTTP instead of using ActiveSync, if only to simplify the instalation process and to cut out an additional layer or communication between the ML Client and Server.  I also see from a post that you made at news://forums.sybase.com/sybase.public.sqlanywhere.mobilink that you've been playing with synchronization using the .NET version of the dbmlsync API and synchronizing using TCPIP.  I did respond to your posting on the newsgroup to explain what I believe is happening in your application.

Are you still interested in figuring out the issues with ActiveSync and WMDC, or are you happy with the solution you've implemented using the dbmlsync API and using TCPIP?

Comment: Just to comment.  The error I am getting is with a Windows Mobile 6.1 device